# how to automatize ggplot plots in a function? - R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, automation

How can **ggplot** be *automatized* (in a function?) such that one can choose which columns to plot. i.e.:
given the following data:

```
DT <- data.frame(y=seq(0,10,1),x=seq(0,20,2),z=seq(0,30,3))
```

I would like to for example: firstly plot **Y against X** and then **Y against Z**
I have tried the (simple) code below, but with no success:

```
fun<- function (y,x){
    Yaxis=paste(y)
    Xaxis=paste(x)

    Plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = DT,
                            aes(x=Yaxis, y=Xaxis))
return(Plot)
}
fun("y","x")
fun("y","z")
```

Comment: Look into non-standard evaluation for ggplot2, ?aes_string should help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
# create the dataset
DT <- data.frame(y=seq(0,10,1),x=seq(0,20,2),z=seq(0,30,3))

# plot data as categorical
fun<- function (df, xaxis, yaxis){
  # convert numeric to character
  Yaxis=paste(df[, yaxis])
  Xaxis=paste(df[, xaxis])
  # create the plot object
  Plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = df,
                                aes(x=Yaxis, y=Xaxis))
  # plot it
  return(Plot)
}
# plot y on horizontal, x on vertical
fun(DT,"y","x")
fun(DT,"y","z")

# plot data as numeric
fun2 <- function (df, xaxis, yaxis){
  Yaxis=df[, yaxis]
  Xaxis=df[, xaxis]

  Plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = df,
                                aes(x=Yaxis, y=Xaxis))
  return(Plot)
}
# plot y on horizontal, x on vertical
fun2(DT,"y","x")
# plot y on horizontal, z on vertical
fun2(DT,"y","z")
```

You can obviously customize the plot further, creating flexible title, axis anotation etc.

Comment: There is no need to create new variables such as `Yaxis`, simply use `aes_string` to be able ot pass `xaxis` directly to `ggplot2`.

Comment: Fair enough, I was probably a bit confused by the use of `paste` in the code and didn't want to remove it completely. You are right that the function could be improved. But I think it still shows how to wrap ggplot into own function to make calling it easier.

Comment: Dear @Paul and @Ira, many thanks...indeed the `aes_string` works perfectly ... I missed that command 
cheers