# Is there any way for adnvanced automatization of plotting using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with columns describing company names (`id`), functions (`category`), indicators (`factors`) and values for these factors. The purpose is to plot several boxplots to show the distribution of factors values by functions.
Data:

```
structure(list(id = c("Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", 
"Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", 
"Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", "Chee, Chelsea", "Hatchett, Dante", 
"Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", 
"Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", "Hatchett, Dante", 
"Hatchett, Dante", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", 
"Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", 
"Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", 
"Hagemeier, Wilmer", "Hagemeier, Wilmer", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", 
"el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", 
"el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", "el-Jabour, Suhaa", 
"el-Jabour, Suhaa", "Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", 
"Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", 
"Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", "Salihi, Divya", "al-Jamil, Jaad", 
"al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", 
"al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", "al-Jamil, Jaad", 
"al-Jamil, Jaad", "Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", 
"Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", 
"Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", "Porter, Elijah", "Ridgley, Matthew", 
"Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", 
"Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", "Ridgley, Matthew", 
"Ridgley, Matthew", "Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", 
"Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", 
"Oats, Jiair", "Oats, Jiair", "Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", 
"Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", 
"Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien", "Thompson, Asien"
), category = c("will", "will", "will", "will", "will", "deal", 
"deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "will", "will", "will", "will", 
"will", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "will", "will", 
"will", "will", "will", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", 
"will", "will", "will", "will", "will", "deal", "deal", "deal", 
"deal", "deal", "will", "will", "will", "will", "will", "deal", 
"deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "will", "will", "will", "will", 
"will", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "will", "will", 
"will", "will", "will", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", 
"will", "will", "will", "will", "will", "deal", "deal", "deal", 
"deal", "deal", "will", "will", "will", "will", "will", "deal", 
"deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "will", "will", "will", "will", 
"will", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal", "deal"), factor = c("f1", 
"f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", 
"f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", 
"f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", 
"f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", 
"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", 
"f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", 
"f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", 
"f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", 
"f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"
), value = c(0.339243657473717, 0.384596983617986, 0.0903604942291727, 
0.622299975399853, 0.878426613848986, 0.619932561033423, 0.768372484010595, 
1.3720186467304, 0.516137222110122, 0.0939216356224454, 0.423330163104718, 
1.09092813025095, 1.19417177287019, 0.719465669220584, 0.452970378504298, 
-0.262289594598489, 1.22689933746316, 0.816430627598565, 0.225885114542236, 
0.632040744287071, 0.104560237280194, 0.381714309901825, 0.62676961473864, 
-0.0497874636348734, 0.950027143102881, 0.770846095346556, 0.148980694426281, 
0.0441704598142616, 0.490668306336729, 1.02471661138678, 0.156174816905824, 
0.31746617387743, 0.156617889567164, 0.0424322867402526, -0.468906139291209, 
0.240259904852959, 0.477319222715837, 0.838721253256597, 0.445074674905288, 
0.549554109125289, -0.226713556713281, 0.118250559860738, 0.479740692801046, 
0.0787136404239509, -0.796681488556265, 0.191482860752725, 0.28786926088113, 
0.87763251227066, 0.0338514723682836, 0.235576477670443, -0.0690121807547427, 
-0.268401095627916, 0.525430078156439, -0.292741297006626, 0.204765160519623, 
0.332993835314161, 0.410545410766758, 0.686637667590553, 0.149842772573679, 
0.700177571955539, 0.945997668337351, 0.32488054941514, 0.993151127821943, 
0.524358293364559, 0.743356027756573, 0.0247172637782763, 0.205738918048416, 
0.922272051144243, 0.264568168014215, 0.800444985485889, 0.0490291076301935, 
-0.182296829387635, 0.275266536310165, 0.723462807292679, 1.37681045703127, 
0.996572375062412, 0.78567025822639, 0.852269626584109, -0.257367673879751, 
0.998810021760118, 0.90491311313343, 1.33803924723801, 1.44241236118906, 
1.20343139126242, 0.666758519859951, 1.0151075718858, 0.820298727592033, 
1.26452544892297, 0.937448475295236, 0.363135203972494, 0.633056112436769, 
0.965685304671053, 0.640992301458128, -0.083835315236123, 1.14088770490309, 
0.402326393668432, 0.117951239403618, 0.403472929718899, 1.32109715429833, 
0.937023659882023)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

I think about automatizing this process. I would like to know how can I:

1. Filter my dataframe within a function for each `will` and `deal`;
2. To make boxplots for factors within each category.

I tried to write a lambda function but did not understand indexing and how to filter tha abstract dataframe which we define in our function. Conceptually, I understand that I am supposed to do something like that:

```
plots_fun <- function(dataframe){
  a <- ggplot(data = dataframe[,1], ...)
}
```

Also, I thought about using `lapply`... But my first step is to write the function -- actually, what I am struggling with.

In the case of my sample data, the desirable output is two plots - for `will` and `deal`:

```
ggplot(data = sample_data %>% filter(category == "will"),
       aes(factor, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()

ggplot(data = sample_data %>% filter(category == "deal"),
       aes(factor, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: I have also done some reserach on question, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025120/how-to-automatize-ggplot-plots-in-a-function-r) does not fit my case, to my mind.

Comment: Have you looked at facets? Could you show what kind of plot you would like to have?

Comment: I am not sure this needs automatisation. This really speaks very loudly "facet" to me.

Comment: if you really need to produce separate plots, there are plenty of threads out there how to do that . This is a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot

Comment: wow, eurica, facets!! thank you, colleagues

Comment: @NelsonGon may be, you know possible ways to facet more than 20 categories? The image (plot) looks messy and unreadable...

Comment: @tjebo or, may be, you?

Comment: plenty of ways. How messy it looks depends **very** much on your device size - don't trust the viewer panel wherever you're previewing your plot. 0) (and most important): re-consider if you really need to show 20 facets. 1) increase the width and height of final plot. 2) remove fonts and decrease font size as much as possible. 3) play around with facet_wrap or facet_grid, number of columns / rows etc

Comment: Related to @tjebo's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816981/how-to-set-adequate-space-for-facet-wrap-in-r